# Xlwings cannot find modules

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

Im using xlwings with RunPython and I have a VBA line `RunPython ("import engine.Comment;engine.Comment.comments()")`

The `Comment.py` file is saved in a folder called `engine`, in the same directory as the Excel file. All this is in G drive but accessible on windows explorer through Google Drive Stream.. This code works on my computer, but either works or doesn't on other computers which are set up just as mine. Running code gives the error `File "<string>",line 1, in <module> ModuleNotFoundError:No module named "engine"` The 'comment()` function isnt referencing any other file.

How can I get this working?